# React date in Select Mysql

Tags: mysql, reactjs, momentjs, axios

How can I select rows from my database with date more than 2017-12-05 but less than 2017-12-12 ?

```
const start = moment().format('YYYY-MM-05');
const end = moment().format('YYYY-MM-12');
```

This is my mysql request:

```
'SELECT id, content, date, own FROM quests 
WHERE  '+start+'>="date" AND "date">='+end+'
ORDER BY date DESC'
```

In my mysql I have date format YYYY-MM-DD. This request select rows with date 0000-00-00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `between` operator

```
'SELECT id, content, date, own FROM quests 
WHERE  `date` BETWEEN \''+start+'\' AND \''+end+'\'
ORDER BY date DESC'
```

Comment: Still the same problem select only date with 0000-00-00

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit. Try now. The date should be in quotes.